# How to change Visual Studio cursor color?

Tags: visual-studio-code, colors

I was making Visual Studio Code stylish so I decided to change the color of the cursor.

I searched on the **Extensions** tab but there were no extensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out and the answer is:

I have to write a few lines of code in **`settings.json`**.

And these are lines:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editorCursor.foreground": "#3a30fe", // light blue
    "terminalCursor.foreground": "#ffffff" // white
}
```

And it worked for me...